# How to delete or modify a user in VisualSvn Server

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I have looked through the MMC console plugin for VisualSVN server, and I can see where to ADD a new user. But I can't find anywhere to delete a user, or edit the user (for example, where to add the user to a group).

I'm sure it's lurking there but I've just missed it.

Note that this is using Subversion Authentication (not integrated NTLM).

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you use Basic Windows authentication or Integrated Windows Authentication then user and group management has to be done via ["Active Directory users and computers"](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754217.aspx) snap-in. If the machine is not in domain, you can manage [local user and group accounts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/user-groups#1TC=windows-7).
- If you use Subversion authentication and authorization, then you should see Users and Groups in VisualSVN Server Manager console under repositories list.

  [image]